SwiftUI - Make Grid row selectable including the text?
In a grid View, here a LazyVGrid, I understand that to make a row "tappable" one should add the .contentShape() modifier with a Rectangle() shape:
LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible()), GridItem(.flexible())]) {
    Text("first column")
    Text("second column")
    // potentially many columns
}
//.overlay(content: { Rectangle().fill() })
.contentShape(Rectangle())
.onTapGesture {
    print("row tapped")
}

However, while the space in the row is now tappable, clicking on the text is not recognized as a tap.  The text is selectable for copying because I have .textSelection(.enabled) on its container.
Is there a way to make the text tappable as well?
And can that be achieved while allowing it to still be selectable?

I have found that using an overlay with a filled Rectangle works, but not if the fill is Color.clear.
I saw an idea to fill with UIColor of System background, but I would rather not import UIKit.
I saw the idea of using a fill with opacity so little that it was not apparent to the user.  Is that really the only way to do it?  (Also the text is no longer selectable.)


put the onTapGesture on the Text not the Grid

Should have specified that this is a grid of two or more columns.  Therefore edited the question.

It is unclear what your desired outcome is. The Texts in your current code is tappable and runs print("row tapped") as expected. If you want tapping the text to trigger another action, add onTapGesture to the Text. If you want tapping the text to trigger another action in addition to print("row tapped"), use a simultaneousGesture.

What kind of layout are you trying to have? A grid of "cards", possibly with a background, such that when you tap a card (which includes background and any text) an action is run? Can you update your question with some reproducible code so there is something more concrete to look at and work with?

You probably need SwiftUI.Grid. You have much more control there.

@loremipsum Putting onTapGesture on each Text does not work. @Sweeper The text in above code is not tappable.  Clicking on the text (macOS) changes the cursor to the text selection cursor. @AndreiG. It's a table of rows and I want to click anywhere within the row including on the text.  The above code reproduces.

I tried a Grid with GridRows and the text in the row is also not tappable.

@TT-- Tapping on the row, including tapping on the text works for me using the code provided, producing "row tapped" output in the console,  when using Preview for either iPhone or mac OS. It is unclear what the problem is at this stage.

I'm thinking this outcome won't be possible since I have used .textSelection(.enabled) on the container.  If I remove that, whole row contents are selectable, but text no longer is (of course).
